# Python 3: pandas group multiindex and mean of 2 separate columns per multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

What code do I need to perform a `mean` of both drugs and health per session by type.

[image]

```
df[['drugs', 'health', 'session', 'type']]
```

these all are currently columns. I though it ought to be indexed by both `session` (first) and then `type`.

```
grouped_S = grouped['session'].as_index=True
grouped_c = grouped['type'].as_index=True
grouped_dh = grouped['drugs', 'health'].mean().as_index=False
```

How do I correct this code to make it work: getting an average of drugs and health per session and by type?

Comment: Please add data, current result and expected result as text. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. Only plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try this:

```
df.groupby(['session', 'type'])[['drugs', 'health']].mean()
```

Comment: Thank you!  Are you a tutor for hire?  I knew it would be a combination of something I tried - just adding the correct bracket(s) and parenthesis.

Comment: @lucylim Yes, contact www.dunderdata.com.  I work thought that site.  DunderData also has great training materials.

Comment: I'm asking for you.  BTW.  I posted another question under the name of query_weary, because I don't want to use my real name.  I did a transform:        
 df = df[df.groupby{'id')['metric'].transform('max')==df['metric]]
and now my other functions don't work.  I tried                                                            df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True) nope!
I tried to start from the very beginning - import libraries and re-read csv's and nope!
what happened?

Comment: There isn't a reason I see why that should work.  Just make sure that df has valid rows.  But `df = df[df.groupby('id')['metric'].transform('max') == df['metric']]` should only filter down to the max records per 'id'.

Comment: Can you paste the link to the other question under query_weary you need help with?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27224334

Comment: @lucylim I added a comment to your question linked above.